# Python is stating my file is not in the directory even though it is saved on my computer. what is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Assume that a file containing a series of integers is named numbers.txt and exists on the
>   computer’s disk. Write a program that calculates the average of all the numbers stored in
>   the file.

I have a file name `numbers_good.tx`t saved on my computer. When I type it in the error reads no file in directory.

```
def main():
    try:
        filename=input("name of the file")
        myfile=open(filename, "r")
    except IOError:
        print("File Error")

main()
```

Comment: Your program works fine for me. If I call it "input.py" and run `python input.py` from the shell prompt and type `input.py` when the program prompts me, I get no error. I wonder if your file is in a different directory from the one you think it is in?

Comment: I think it is, how do i change the path directory?

Comment: Note that you should always use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) to open files in Python.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely an issue with relative paths. Probably for some reason working directory for your program is not the one you expect.

Try this program to see, where Python is actually looking for your file.

```
import os.path

filename = input("name of the file: ")
print(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

You should either input absoulte path or move your file into the working directory (you can deduce it from the output of the program I posted).

Comment: thank you. unfortunately i amm able to use your code. i have to stick to the format i have written due to the program being an assignment.

Comment: @DaveLee  I think you are missing kirelagin 's point:  He's showing you how you can see what the full path is, so that you can see if it matches what you'd expect.  W.r.t. the assignment, you can presumably write whatever code you'd like, as long as it works.  So, for instance, you can create a string variable which is either path you'd like to search in, or the home path of the executable.  Then paste the file name to that path & voila, it is now looking in the proper place.

Comment: +1: @kirelagin's code will help diagnose the problem (i.e. where the Python script thinks the file should be) even if it it cannot be used in the assignment *per se*.

Comment: A simple mistake that most of us might make is that we may hide the extension of a file (usually happens in windows). There might be a chance that you created a txt file and then given it the name numbers.txt while hiding the extension. Effectively the filename will be numbers.txt.txt